# Partitions of integers, a series for infinite product $(1+q)(1+q^3)(1+q^5)\cdots$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, infinite-product

Show that
$$
  (1+q)(1+q^3)(1+q^5) \cdots = 
  1+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{q^{k^2}}{(1-q^2)(1-q^4)(1-q^6) \cdots (1-q^{2k})}.$$

How would one proceed combinatorially. What I know is that the left-hand side counts Ferrers diagrams with distinct odd parts and the right counts self-conjugate partitions with Durfee number k.

Comment: Hint: Take a partition counted by the right hand side. Peel off its first column and the first row. From the result, again, peel off the first column and the first row. And so on...

Comment: How do I know how many elements are in the first column and first row? All I know is that the resulting diagram is still of the same kind, but it has a smaller Durfee number (in fact, 1 less).

Comment: Of the same kind? Your original diagram is self-conjugate; the new one won't be, but it will have some other nice properties...